# Difficult scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

Using Xcode 10.1

I have a tableview inside a scrollview.  Even though the table is larger than the scrollview and there are filled cells in those rows, it's very difficult to get the scroll to work in the simulator.

After multiple attempts using the mouse to scroll the table, I get a very thin scroll indicator that works (meaning I am able to scroll to bottom of table) intermittently.  I need to keep playing with the table to get it to come back again.  I also tried adjusting the inset but that just moves it from the edge, still razor thin.

Any ideas where I can look to solve?

Comment: Why did you put a table view in a scroll view? A table view *is* a scroll view.

Comment: All the examples I've seen used a scrollview to start.  I don't need a scrollview, just a tableview, to have a table that scrolls and fills the entire  View sans tabbars?

Comment: Check out this link it's really descriptive with lots of pictures to help you: [link](https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/)

Comment: If you find an example that puts a table view inside a scroll view, I suggest you move on and find a better example.

Comment: I took scrollview off the XIB and teh tableview that remains shows the rows but I can't scroll.  The rows stop at the bottom of the view.  I guess I don't understand how tableviews resize (specifically the height) as rows are added.  Scrolling in enabled.  Do I need to set a constraint on the height?  How do I do that?  Where would I place that "Table1 changed height" code.  Does it occur at NumberOfRowsInSection?